# socket io not parse string and any characters

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want send simple message to node.js console from html. But number is working , string and any characters not working,
Display message is 
message:  NaN

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile('sample.html', {
    root:'/home/deneebo/Documents/apidevelopment/nodejs'});
});
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
        console.log('message: ', + msg);});
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

below  html code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>

  </head>
  <body>

    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m"  autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
     alert($('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');

    return false;
  });
</script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: please add your html code, the script part which sends text to node.js console?

Comment: thank for quick comments, this my html code

Comment: i did not change any thing in html...work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried your code my local work well

```
    var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){

  res.sendfile('stack.html', {root: __dirname });
});
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
        console.log('message: ',  msg);}); //Remove + from here
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

[image]

Comment: ok fine. but this code does not work for me,  could you help me?

Comment: yeah i am here what still wrong with your code update me

Comment: Numbers also working, but string or character mean return 'message:  NaN'

Comment: buts its working for me did you remove + sign near msg